# how to change http://apps.facebook.com/domain to https://facebook.com/domain

Tags: facebook

I create mini website inside facebook the url to minisite is

http://apps.facebook.com/domain

I want to change it to

https://facebook.com/domain

I want to take out the string "apps" from the url address.

How can I do that

many thanks

Comment: Can you explain in detail , Are you asking in code?

Comment: maybe It is process, I can not find the manual that corresponds to it I know this should be a guide but I do not know exactly what to look for, maybe it is a matter of definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've created an application on Facebook so as far as I know its not possible to remove app from the URL as its default sub domain of Facebook to define application URL and URL "http://www.facebook.com/xyz" is the URL for user identification.

You can easily find any user with just "http://www.facebook.com/username" so I think that URL its default to identify user not any app / site.

Answer (score 2):

The **apps** subdomain is used for canvas applications.  The **www** subdomain is for profiles and pages.  The only was to have your application on the www subdomain is to install it as a tab application on the page of some entity, like a business, product, etc.

If you install your app as a tab, the URL will resemble this: https://www.facebook.com/activatedrinks/app_431623466868678